# XNA Depth Map Overlapping Areas Color

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, hlsl, depth

I'm trying to draw a depth map of a scene.
Now, I made an HLSL file like the one in: http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Shadow_map.php
And everything went just fine. However! I want to find out the exact value of each pixel, so instead of drawing on the normal render target, I created a new render target which is a Texture2D as in: http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php
and then I drew it using a spritebatch.

Then! when I display the images, the first, that is, the one drawing directly to the screen gives this output:

[image: Correct Depth Image]

and the one that draws to a texture then to the screen using a sprite gives this:
[image: Sprite drawn Image]

Notice how in the second capture, the right arm of the body, which is obviously behind the body, is drawn as if the body doesn't exist in the overlapping area.

I think, its an ordering problem, as the vertices in the front are drawn first to the texture then the more distant ones overwriting the closer ones resulting in the observed image.

I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpriteBatch` [modifies the graphics device state](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) when you use it. From the linked article, here is what it sets:

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.None;
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;
```

You probably want to set the depth-stencil state back to default (depth read and write).

```
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

You may also have to set some other states, depending on what you need for your rendering.

Comment: +1: Completely agree.  In this circumstance, I usually put a breakpoint before the `SpriteBatch.Begin()` call and check the `DepthStencilState`, `BlendState` and `RasterizerState`, and then reset them all after the `SpriteBatch.End()` call.